# Difference between Taylor Series Expansion and Taylor Series

Tags: taylor-expansion, definition

Is there a difference in the meaning of **Taylor Series** and **Taylor Series Expansion**?
For example:

The **Taylor Series** of the exponential function about $0$ is:  $$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Whereas the **Taylor Series Expansion** about $0$ is: $$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ...$$

Is this correct? I don't mean to be overly pedantic, but I am interested in knowing if there is actually a difference in their definitions. Thank you!

Comment: Difference between what and what? In fact $\sum\frac{x^n}{x!}$ and $1+x+\dots$ are exactly the same expansion, in different _notation_. So you asking about the difference between something and itself.

Comment: I am asking if there is a difference. Perhaps Taylor Series is strictly reserved for the summation notation where as Taylor Series Expansion is reserved for the "expanded" notation. I know that both are equal to $e^x$, I was just wondering about the wording.

Comment: "I am asking if there is a difference." I understood that - that's why I explained that there is no difference. There is no difference between $4$ and $2+2$; they're exactly the  same  thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same. The Taylor series is an *expansion* of a function into an infinite sum.

Both the Sigma notation and the pattern form you listed are equivalent—the summation form is somewhat more rigorous when it comes to notation as it provides a precise definition for the infinite series, while the second way you wrote is a way to quickly grasp intuitively what the series looks like. But it has nothing to do with one being an expansion and the other not.

The goal is for a person reading to be able to grasp precisely how one constructs the terms in the infinite series, so authors will use the representations interchangeably depending on the context.

Comment: Thank you very much, that clears everything up!